# How the IP addresses of a subnet distributed between azure functions?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have to implement Azure Functions for first time and I am struggling with the decision about the **size of my subnet**. I want to create a function app and use App service plan with it.
For now, I do not know how many functions I will have in one function app and also not sure how much I will need to scale my function app.

Well, the documentation says, that the IPs are not assigned to a specific function, but to a function app. Does it mean, that I do not need to care, even if I run 50 functions in the same function app?
So I only need additional IPs when I want to scale my function app or create many function apps?

So as long as do not scale my function app, but have let's say 50 functions in it, I will be fine with just /28 subnet for my linux functions?

I was reading about networking options for Azure functions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-cli.

**Still, I do not understand how exactly the IP addresses will be distributed? **

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function app you have to make use of a subnet that is large enough to accommodate whatever scale your app might reach to scale up or down your function app in terms of size or SKU.

You can make sure of premium function plans for windows /24 with 256 addresses and /26 with 64 addresses for Linux so that it doesn't cause any subnet capacity issues.

While creating virtual network you can change the addresses like below:

[image]

[image]

If you don't want to scale the function app, for Linux functions a ***/28 subnet is sufficient.*** App will use for outbound communication. This subnet size can provide you with up to 16 usable IP addresses. This should be sufficient for a moderate number of functions within a single Function App

If you need to scale your function app, you can add additional IP addresses to the subnet. You can add another subnet to virtual network so you will have an additional 64 IP addresses used to assign in your function app.

[image]

So, as long as you don't scale your function app, but you have 50 functions in it, you will be fine with /28 subnet for your Linux functions.

In function app -> Networking ->Virtual Network Integration select the virtual network that contains the subnet that you want to use like below:

[image]

[image]

> Still, I do not understand how exactly the IP addresses will be
> distributed?

Ip addresses are distributed. While creating subnet in portal during the process of integrating with the virtual network Ip, the IP addresses will be assigned to the subnet1. The resources deployed to the subnet2 then make use of the IP addresses.